# al instalar npm install me arroja este error: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\magal.....package.json',

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Al escribir `npm install` me envía el siguiente error, he intentado con muchas cosas para poder corregir y no he tenido éxito, les apreciaría mucho si alguien puede ayudarme

[image: Error npm]

Comment: te recomendaría que revises este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json

Comment: @DavidFernándezFlores muchas gracias por contestar y por la recomendación, en este momento me dispongo a revisarlo!!!! GRACIAS!!! :D

Comment: Puedes dar mas detalle, que libreria o proyecto estás intentando instalar?

Comment: ¿Tienes el archivo [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json)? Recuerda que este archivo es de vital importancia para el correcto funcionamiento de `npm`, ya que entre otras cosas, ahí se defienen las dependencias que se tienen que instalar a través de `npm`. Si no lo tienes puedes hacer un `npm init` y luego instalar las dependencias explícitamente.